# Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0 forward path variable

Tags: java, spring, gateway

How to forward a path variable in Spring Cloud Gateway 2.0?

If we have an microservice that has 2 endpoints: `/users` and `/users/{id}` and is running on port 8080, how to forward the request to the endpoint with the id path variable?

The following gateway configuration successfully forwards to the `/users` end point, but the second route forwards the request to the same `/users` endpoint of the real service.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route("users", t -> t.path("/users").uri("http://localhost:8080/users"))
        .route("userById", t -> t.path("/users/**").uri("http://localhost:8080/users/"))
        .build();
}
```

I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` from spring cloud `Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `rewritePath` filter has to be used:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("users", t -> t.path("/users")
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/users"))
            .route("userById", t -> t.path("/users/**")
                .filters(rw -> rw.rewritePath("/users/(?<segment>.*)", "/users/${segment}"))
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/users/"))
        .build();
    }
```

The YAML version is specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#rewritepath-gatewayfilter-factory):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/foo/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: I am not sure you're not actually invoking the service directly without running through the gateway, because your gateway path seems to be the same as your service path. Could you try to change the gateway path and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, please find below what worked for me. Both methods produce the same result.

Here is my set-up:

- the gateway is running on `http://localhost:8090`
- a base path called `/context` serves as the entry point of the gateway
- a service called `my-resources` running on `http://localhost:8091/my-resources`. When `/my-resources` is invoked without parameters, it returns all resources. When it is invoked with a parameters it returns the resource with the corresponding `RID` (if any)

The gateway is configured so that all path variables (possibly none) transmitted to `http://localhost:8090/context/my-resources/` is forwarded to uri `http://localhost:8091/my-resources/`.

#### Method 1: using `application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route_id
        predicates:
        - Path=/context/my-resources/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/context/my-resources/(?<RID>.*), /my-resources/$\{RID}
        uri: http://localhost:8091
```

#### Method 2: using Java like configuration

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder) {
    return routeBuilder.routes()
            .route("route_id",
                    route -> route
                            .path("/context/my-resources/**")
                            .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/context/my-resources/(?<RID>.*)", "/my-resources/${RID}"))
                            .uri("http://localhost:8091")
            )
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I was able to make it work using routes for multiple services. In this case, I used the "aplication.properties" file instead of a "yml" file.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=service-sample
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://service-samp
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/sample/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/api/sample/(?<segment>.*), /api/sample/${segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=service-test-new
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://service-test
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/test/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RewritePath=/api/test/(?<segment>.*), /api/test/${segment}
```